# Help understanding 1986 schematic for Rohde & Schwarz cryptographic key generator

Tags: schematics, random-number

From https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/rs/pu104/index.htm :-

> PU-104 was a key generator for perforated paper tape, made around 1986 by Rohde & Schwarz (R&S) in München (Munich, Germany). The device was able to create long sequences of truly random numbers and send them to external paper tape puncher via its built-in V.24 interface.

I'm trying to understand how random noise was sampled by the CPU.  I don't think that they used an dedicated analogue to digital converter, but rather went directly from analogue to digital logic. I can't follow what happens after the  noise enters the purple square in the following schematic extract:-

[image: noise]

The extract is from the complete user manual at https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/rs/pu104/files/pu104s2_manual.pdf.  See pages 24-27 of the PDF file. The 'bottom' board [photograph](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/rs/pu104/img/301967/029/full.jpg) clearly shows two PM156 op-amps which I cannot locate on the schematics. They're not of a style I'm accustomed to.

It don't know why there are two schematics.

Comment: "directly from analogue to digital logic" <-- that *is* an ADC, just a 1-bit ADC. (don't laugh, these exist, even as separate components.)

Comment: page 29 defines D21–D24 to be SN75150AP line drivers, if that helps. An RS-232 line driver, to be exact.

Comment: V for transistors and diodes, that's interesting. Never seen that before. Probably short for a German word, since it's a German company.

Comment: @Hearth - the Vx naming convention is a holdover from the days of vacuum tubes (valves) which were used in equivalent transistor and diode applications.

Comment: @PeterSmith Ooh, that makes sense. I didn't realize the designator got carried over to semiconductor devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't look like a noise generating circuit.

According to the BOM on page 29, D21 to D24 are SN75150AP, so RS-232 line drivers, which need a dual +-12V supply. That's exactly what V1 and V2 are doing: being rough, regulated power supply. I'm not sure, but V3 and V4 being [BZX79-C13](https://www.nexperia.com/products/diodes/zener-diodes/BZX79-C13.html) have a ~ 13V Zener voltage – these might simply be protection diodes.

Generally, your PDF is the manual and service manual to the V.24 serial interface card, not to the board that generates the randomness.

Comment: I see what you mean. That transistor/diode arrangement is   the same  as for producing Zener avalanche noise, which I've used and see all over the Interweb.  I didn't expect R23/24 to be so low though. 39K perhaps, but not 390 Ohms so perhaps you're right. The implication is that the entire RNG circuit is missing from the PDF.

Comment: as said, you're barking up the wrong PDF! You've got the service manual for the V.24 board, not for the RNG board.